# Is there a way to write the next expression without the IF statement? if ((b & 1) != 0)

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I'm programming on a GPU, and I want to speed up my implementation by replacing this expression

```
if ((b & 1) != 0)
```

with an equivalent, but without using the IF statement. 
The code is written in C, this call is inside a CUDA kernel function.

### EDIT, full function below, one more IF statement to eliminate below:

```
unsigned char p = 0;
unsigned char counter;
unsigned char carry;
for (counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++)
{
    if ((b & 1) != 0)
    {
         p ^= a;
    }
    carry = (unsigned char)(a & 0x80);
    a <<= 1;
    if (carry != 0)
    {
        a ^= 0x1B; 
    }
    b >>= 1;
}
return p;
```

---

Sorry for not answering earlier, this is the full chunk of code for the function. Now I noticed I have another IF statement, I apologize, a bit tired, missing stuff.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can shorten it to `if (b&1)` Other than that, noone can tell you how to omit an if statement without knowing what the body of your if statement does.

Comment: ...clarification would be useful.  The if statement as you've given it doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @m24p: And since it doesn't do anything, you can speed it up by deleting it altogether (though an optimizing compiler is likely to do that for you).

Comment: there are exist several techniques which can eliminate such IF, can you provide full if statement (with else if there is one)

Comment: This is a misguided approach to code optimization.  The compiler will aggressively use predicated execution to eliminate branching in the code (that you might expect from an `if` statement).

Comment: Sorry updating code right now.

Comment: I updated the question after the request from above users, and AlexD solved the question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think that the post was voted against before the edit. I believe that it could be now helpful to next users, if completed with (positive or negative) meaningful answers. I'm voting to reopen. I also think that we have been a bit negative with the OP to downvote his post so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking (but not sure if it improves performance, might be vice versa) you could replace

```
if ((b & 1) != 0)
{
     p ^= a;
}
```

with

```
p ^= a * (b & 1);
```

---

Similarly,

```
carry = (unsigned char)(a & 0x80);
a <<= 1;
if (carry != 0)
{
    a ^= 0x1B; 
}
```

can be replaced with

```
carry = (unsigned char)(a >> 7);
a <<= 1;
a ^= 0x1B * carry;
```

---

Assuming [two's complement] arithmetic, we could get rid of possibly expensive multiplication:

```
x = (b & 1) ^ 1; // 0 if last bit of b is set, 1 otherwise
x -= 1;          // 0->FF, 1->0
p ^= a & x;
```

or just

```
p ^= a & (((b & 1) ^ 1) - 1);
```

And

```
carry = a >> 7;
a <<= 1;
a ^= 0x1B & ((carry ^ 1) - 1);
```

(**Disclaimer**: done with a piece of paper, should be tested for correctness.)

Comment: Thanks Alex, that should do the trick. It should speed it up because CUDA is very sensitive to IF calls (I have been told at least). 
Sorry I can't upvote, not enough rep :(

Comment: For the second one I was thinking more like:
a ^= 0x1B * (carry >> 7)
I'll test it, I'm sure I can get it to work now.

Comment: @Yondaime It should be a simple bit-hack to get rig of multiplication too. Basically, you want `1->FF`, `0->0`, and then `&` instead of `*`. Once again, while it should work in principle, please verify the correctness.

Comment: @Yondaime `a ^= 0x1B * (carry >> 7)` It should give the same result, but with an extra operation (`&` and `>>` instead of just `>>`).

Comment: @Yondaime Just 2 more cents. I just illustrated how we could get rid of multiplication.

Comment: The will do comment was about multiplication :)

Comment: @Yondaime Ah, got it. I thought it was answer to my "_please verify the correctness_" :).

Comment: I tend to agree with @RobertCrovella that this is a misguided approach to code optimization. I have built a full test code and benchmarked your two alternative approaches against the original one. However, on my GeForce GT540M, I have found no improvements from your optimized snippets. The full codes along with the results on my card are available [here](http://pastebin.com/6yV2Jzx2).

Comment: I have tested the mentioned codes also on a Kepler K20c and the results are the following: `original = 1.621ms`, `modified1 = 2.195`, `modified2 = 2.289`.

Comment: @JackOLantern It is hard for me to agree or disagree, I'm not an expert in CUDA at all :). Please see the very first line of my post, in brackets.

Comment: Alex, we are here to help. Answers should have a certain degree of confidency, especially when upvoted multiple times. I wonder if the OP have had the chance to make his own testing :)

Comment: @JackOLantern Sure, do not understand me wrong. Your comments are valuable. They just sounded like I was focusing on optimization, while I was showing how bit manipulation can be used instead of branching.

Comment: I think that your manipulations are interesting, but they will be effective for cpu processing, not gpgpu. For example, consider the first if statement. All the threads in the warp will evaluatd the condition, but only some of them will execute the branching instruction. The remaining threads will just wait idle.

Comment: If you compact the first if in a single instruction you will likely not reduce the overall number of clock cycles of a warp.